# How to get first 2 non zero digits after decimal in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to get the first 2 non zero digits from a decimal number. How can this be achieved?

Suppose I have number like 0.000235 then I need 0.00023, if the number is 0.000000025666 then my function should return 0.000000025.

Can any one have an idea of how this can be achieved in javascript?

The result should be a float number not a string.

Comment: What if the number is greater than 1 ?

Comment: I will handle it separately in if condition.

Comment: Are you aware that 0.000000025666 is converted to scientific notation 2.5666e-8?  This sort of thing interferes with looking for the string '0'.

Comment: What answer would you want if the number was 0.0002035 ?

Comment: If the number is 0.0002035 then the output should be 0.00020

Comment: I think u should specify if the result should be a number type (float) or rather string. It depends if you want just the number to send it somewhere (so doesn't matter how the string representation looks like) or if you want string to display it in nice form.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are two faster solutions (see [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/round-to-2-significant-digits)) :

**Solution 1 :**

```
var n = 0.00000020666;
var r = n.toFixed(1-Math.floor(Math.log(n)/Math.log(10)));
```

Note that this one doesn't round to the smallest value but to the nearest : `0.0256` gives `0.026`, not `0.025`. If you really want to round to the smallest, use this one :

**Solution 2 :**

```
var r = n.toFixed(20).match(/^-?\d*\.?0*\d{0,2}/)[0];
```

It works with negative numbers too.

Comment: That's pretty cool, but wouldn't `0.0256 === 0.026`, it rounds

Comment: I see you added the result should be a floating point number. In that case you should wrap it in `parseFloat`

Comment: If you want to have **Solution 1** working for both positive and negative numbers, you need the absolute value of `n` in the logarithm, i.e. `n.toFixed(1-Math.floor(Math.log(Math.abs(n))/Math.log(10)))`

Comment: Also if you want **Solution 1** to work for values other than 0.xxxxx..., for example, 75.000002566, you can use the modulus operator: `n.toFixed(1 - Math.floor(Math.log(Math.abs(n % 1)) / Math.log(10))`

Comment: **n.toFixed** is really really bugged

Answer (score 3):

```
var myNum = 0.000256
var i = 1
while(myNum < 10){
    myNum *= 10
    i *= 10
}
var result = parseInt(myNum) / i
```

Comment: +1 This is the solution you are after praveen, see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3QF5n/1/)

Comment: @urbz this function not returning 0.20 if the number is 0.2056

Comment: I don't get it? This has the same issue as all the downvoted answers, it doesn't account for scientific notation, so `0.000000025666` would still be `2.5666e-8` after running through parseInt ?

Comment: @praveen It's returning  0.2. So as you specified in the question if you want to receive float number not a string, that's the correct representation of 0.20 as a float type.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mNLpP/ <- In fact, @dystroy 's first answer with regex matching is better than this ?

Answer (score 2):

With numbers that has that many decimals, you'd have to return a string, as any parsing as number would return scientific notation, as in `0.000000025666` would be `2.5666e-8`

```
function round(n, what) {
    var i = 0;
    if (n < 1) {
        while(n < 1) {
            n = n*10;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return '0.' + (new Array(i)).join('0') + n.toFixed(what).replace('.','').slice(0,-1);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sw6p6/1/)

Comment: My solutions are simpler and much more fast : http://jsperf.com/round-to-2-significant-digits ;)

Comment: @dystroy - yes they are, mine return a string, but yours with the regex is better, that's why I commented on the other answer, as I couldn't understand why it got all the upvotes, it still had the same issues as the regex solutions, but the regex solution seemed better to me.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below code:

```js
function keepNonZeroDecimalPlaces(number, minDecimalPlaces) {
    const numStr = number.toString();
    let result = '';
    let decimalCount = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < numStr.length; i++) {
        const char = numStr.charAt(i);
        if (char === '.') {
            result += char; // Keep the decimal point
        } else if (char !== '0' || decimalCount > 0) {
            result += char;
            if (char !== '0') {
                decimalCount++;
            }
            if (decimalCount >= minDecimalPlaces) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return parseFloat(result);
}

// Example usage
const number1 = 0.00003135110744878017;
const result1 = keepNonZeroDecimalPlaces(number1, 3);
console.log(result1); // Output: 0.00000313

const number2 = 0.000010255258583418511;
const result2 = keepNonZeroDecimalPlaces(number2, 4);
console.log(result2); // Output: 0.00000103
```

Comment: Running the code snippet returns the wrong results ...