# JS decimal number problem need a function similar to toFixed()

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal, tofixed

```
var num = 20.3698  //20.37
var num = 0.36587  //0.37
var num = 0.000014247 //0.000014
var num = 0.0000000000099879 //0.000000000001
```

I am facing a problem in my JavaScript code: I have some random large and small decimal numbers which on printing takes too much space on view pane.

Example:
`var num = 0.023810002044` is okay because here I can use `toFixed(2)` but numbers like this 0.00000000008824721 take much space and if I use `toFixed(2)` then it will give me 0.00 but I want 0.00000000009 and if given a number like 0.03248 then output should be 0.03.

Comment: If you are okay with scientific notations, you could try `Number.toPrecision()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get first 2 non zero digits after decimal in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887400/how-to-get-first-2-non-zero-digits-after-decimal-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the logarithm of 10 and adjust smaller numbers.

```js
const
    fix = v => v > 0.01
        ? v.toFixed(2)
        : v.toFixed(1 - Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(v))));
    
console.log([20.3698, 0.36587, 0.000014247, 0.00000000008824721, 0.0000000000099879].map(fix));
```